# Simple CSS codes works on Windows, but not on Mac (no answers found on the internet)

Tags: html, css, macos

While I was working on a simple CSS&HTML tutorial, I came cross a weird problem; my CSS effect doesn't work at all when I test my codes locally on all the browsers on my Mac (Safari, Firefox, and Chrome). However, with the same files (and same structure of folders), it works perfect on Windows 7's IE --- the fonts of "p" and "h1" change accordingly! 
Here is what I've tired:

- Deleting and adding the codes in the "link" tag, but no changes on the webpage.(it proves that there is no CSS effect)
- Use the developer tools from Chrome to detect if the link is valid. It shows that the css file is linked to the html file.
- Try use TextWrangler instead of TextEdit; no luck
- To check the spelling error; even to copy and paste the codes from the tutorial website.
- To test the code on jsfiddle.net, and the codes work perfectly.
- To test the HTML file on W3C validator, no related error is detected(beside the doc type declaration).

My friends, please help me on this because I have spent hours already, and I am very frustrated because I cannot go on my tutorials  if this issue can't be solved. I have found no answers on the net worked to this issue specifically so I decided to sign up here to ask the question myself. Any kind help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

***** HTML code ****

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Why I love Taos, N.M.</h1>
    <h2>The sun is strong and the people are weird.</h2>
    <p>Taos is a small town in the mountains of northern New Mexico. It's cooler
    than the southern part of the state, because it's 7,000 feet high. Many of the
    residents are high, too. (But not me. I'm weird without any help.)</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

***** CSS code *****

```
p {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 5em;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: *Times New Roman* and *Trebuchet Ms* only exist on Windows.

Comment: Open your browsers developer tools and check for errors in the console. Are you running it from a server, or from the file system? The path to the CSS file may not be correct.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I know Mac might not have this fonts, but the size of the font doesn't work as well.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: I am running from my computer locally, and I did not find any errors in the console. However, when I clicked on the source tab from the developer tool, and try to put a "space" (deleting a letter and adding it back works as well) in the "styles.css" window , then the CSS works! But when I refresh the page, then it goes back to the original which has no CSS at all.  Any thoughts my friends? @@

Comment: From the source tab in the developer tool (on Chrome) , I found that most of the time, the codes in the "styles.css" tab went garbled. However, sometimes, it is normal. When the codes appear normally, the CSS can work if I re-edit the codes in the "styles.css" tab, but it went back to original state (no CSS effect) when I refresh the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! The problem is that the encoding of the html file is different from the encoding of the CSS file. Originally, the html file use UTF-16LE and CSS file use windows-1252. Then, I tired to copy the same codes to a new html file and save it in UTF-8, then it works amazingly! Thank you guys for all your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the '/' in link url(href)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

write it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
```

Because some browsers have trouble in this root '/' format.

Comment: "Because some browsers have trouble in this root '/' format." [citation needed] (That would only be a problem if the path is wrong, which may or may not be the case, as the OP did not provide enough info.)

Comment: @Aabha Pandey: Thanks for the reply. However, deleting the '/' doesn't work. @@

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Worked perfectly on my PC at home, but not on my Mac at work with the latest OS (Sierra 10.12.5). I wasted hours upon hours overnight trying to figure it out, else not be able to do this same exact tutorial at work (w/o a Windows laptop). I had issues with the exact same code.

Turns out it was just the quotation marks for me. The UTF already matched for both files, so that didn't resolve anything for me. I had noticed it always changed my quotations to a tilt, and sometimes they would even be gibberish when I opened the files. Changing the entire font solved nothing. I resolved this by going into Preferences>Options and unchecking "smart quotes". Actually, I just unchecked **everything** making it literally plain text. Almost all the options were checked by default, such as smart dashes, smart copy/paste, spell checking, etc. Worked like a charm.

Don't forget you also must check plain text in Preferences (which the author makes apparent), as well as "Display HTML files as HTML code instead of formatted text" in the next window "Open and Save" to get it to open correctly with the code in TextEdit, else it opens like a web page. The author didn't make that second part apparent. I had to google it, finding a corresponding YouTube video.

I hope this helps someone, either doing the same tutorial (book), or just coding HTML & CSS on a Mac in general, and saves them the buttload of time I lost.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that windows in non-case sensitive but mac is. Try renaming style.css to Style.css